# Listing Children Files from a list of Parent files Google Drive SDK

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I was wondering if it's possible to get a `list` of children files within parent folders like below. I'm finding parent folders that include certain search criteria, and then when those folders are in a `list`, I am cycling through them to find all of the files within those folders. The problem is that using the variable `folder_id` in `files.list()` inputs a `string` of `"folder_id"`, not the actual `folder id`. When I manually enter an `id`, it runs just fine.

```
def get_file_ids(service, search=None, max_files=250):

folder_ids= {}
file_ids = {}
response = service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                     spaces='drive',
                                     fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)').execute()
items = response.get('files', [])     

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
    return None


for item in items:
    #print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    if search is None or item['name'].find(search) > -1:
        folder_ids[item['id']]=item['id']        

for folder_id in folder_ids:
    children = service.files().list(q="'folder_id' in parent", fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)').execute()

    for child in children.get('files', []):
        file_ids[child['name']]=child['id'] 


return file_ids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children query isn't including the folder ID. The query looks like this:

```
'folder_id' in parent
```

when it should be like this:

```
'12312' in parents
```

try [updating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) the child [query](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) to include the folder ID, for example:

```
query = "'{}' in parents".format(folder_id)
children = service.files().list(q=query, 
                                fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)').execute()
```

Comment: I'm getting a HttpError 400: "Invalid Value" error when I run the script with this

Comment: Can you print the query string to check that the [format](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) correct?